# Slow MySQL on category pages queries after importing product reviews

Tags: magento2, category, sql, slow-response

I recently imported over 1 thousand client reviews. Right after importing categories and filters went extremely slow. I found the following SQL to be cause, but I cannot find how to change it to keep the reviews and get the site back to normal. Anyone can help ?

Thanks !

````
COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id),
ROUND(MAX(price_index.min_price ) * 1, 100) AS `max`,
ROUND(MIN(price_index.min_price ) * 1, 100) AS `min`,
STDDEV_SAMP(ROUND((price_index.min_price ) * 1, 100)) AS `std`
FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=13
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `_inv` ON _inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=0
 LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id
WHERE (price_index.min_price IS NOT NULL);```
````

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of EXPLAIN (your query); ?